# Did start spark job server properly and out of memory response

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I am using spark-jobserver-0.6.2-spark-1.6.1

(1) export OBSERVER_CONFIG = /custom-spark-jobserver-config.yml

(2)./server_start.sh

Execution of the above start shell file returns without error. However, it created a pid file: spark-jobserver.pid

When I cat spark-jobserver.pid, the pid file shows pid=126633

However when I ran

lsof -i :9999 | grep LISTEN

It shows

java    126634   spark   17u   IPv4   189013362    0t0   TCP  *:distinct (LISTEN)

I deployed my scala application to job server below, it returned with OK

curl --data-binary @analytics_2.10-1.0.jar myhost:8090/jars/myservice

OK

When I ran the following curl command to test REST service deployed on job server

curl -d "{data.label.index:15, data.label.field:ROOT_CAUSE,input.stri                               ng:[\"tt: Getting operation. \"]}" 'myhost:8090/jobs?                               appName=myservice&classPath=com.test.Test&sync=true&timeout=400'

I got the following out of memory returned response

{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "result": {
    "errorClass": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
    "cause": "unable to create new native thread",
    "stack": ["java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)", "java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)", "org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadP                               ool.startThread(QueuedThreadPool.java:441)", "org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.doStart(QueuedThreadPool.java:108)", "org.spark-pr                               oject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)", "org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(Ag                               gregateLifeCycle.java:81)", "org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)", "org.spark-project.jetty.serve                               r.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)", "org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)", "org.spark-project.jetty                               .util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)", "org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.org$apache$spark$ui$JettyUtils$$connect$1(Jetty                               Utils.scala:252)", "org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(JettyUtils.scala:262)", "org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(JettyUti                               ls.scala:262)", "org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1988)", "scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreac                               h$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)", "org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1979)", "org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.startJettyServer(Je                               ttyUtils.scala:262)", "org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.bind(WebUI.scala:137)", "org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:481)", "                               org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:481)", "scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)", "org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:481)", "spark.jobserver.context.DefaultSparkContextFactory$$anon$1.(SparkContextFactory.scala:53)", "spark.jobserver.co                               ntext.DefaultSparkContextFactory.makeContext(SparkContextFactory.scala:53)", "spark.jobserver.context.DefaultSparkContextFactory.makeContext(SparkCon                               textFactory.scala:48)", "spark.jobserver.context.SparkContextFactory$class.makeContext(SparkContextFactory.scala:37)", "spark.jobserver.context.Defau                               ltSparkContextFactory.makeContext(SparkContextFactory.scala:48)", "spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor.createContextFromConfig(JobManagerActor.scala:378)                               ", "spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$wrappedReceive$1.applyOrElse(JobManagerActor.scala:122)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp                               .apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.ru                               ntime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)", "ooyala.common.akka.ActorStack$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorSt                               ack.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFuncti                               on$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)", "ooyala                               .common.akka.Slf4jLogging$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply$mcV$sp(Slf4jLogging.scala:26)", "ooyala.common.akka.Slf4jLogging$class.ooya                               la$common$akka$Slf4jLogging$$withAkkaSourceLogging(Slf4jLogging.scala:35)", "ooyala.common.akka.Slf4jLogging$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Slf4jLogg                               ing.scala:25)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFuncti                               on$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)", "scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)", "ooyala                               .common.akka.ActorMetrics$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorMetrics.scala:24)", "akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)", "ooyala.co                               mmon.akka.InstrumentedActor.aroundReceive(InstrumentedActor.scala:8)", "akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)", "akka.actor.ActorC                               ell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)", "akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)", "akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)", "akka.di                               spatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)", "scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask                               .java:260)", "scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)", "scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Fo                               rkJoinPool.java:1979)", "scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)"],
    "causingClass": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError",
    "message": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread"

My question

(1) Why processID is different as shown in pid file ?  126633 vs 126634 ?

(2) Why spark-jobserver.pid is created ?  Does this mean spark job server is not started properly ?

(3) How to start job server properly ?

(4) What causes out of memory response ? How to resolve it ?  Is this because I did not set Heap Size or memory correctly ?  How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Jobserver binds to 8090 and not to 9999, may be you should look for that  process id.
2. Spark jobserver pid is created for tracking purpose. It does not mean that job server is not started properly.
3. You are starting spark-jobserver properly.
4. May be try increasing value of JOBSERVER_MEMORY, default is 1G. Did you check on Spark UI whether application started properly?